# Delete list items using Node.js Express Mongoose

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to delete elements after retrieving them from the database using mongoose. However i am stuck at a part where i do not know how to 'grab' one particular element in the list and then how to delete it.

In my app, i have a list of users and their age. 
Here is my **userview.ejs** (EDITED after adding frontend.js)

```html
<meta charset="UTF8">
<link href="../public/javascripts/frontend.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/userlist.css">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic SC' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=NTR' rel='stylesheet'>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Userlist</title>
        <script src="javascripts/frontend.js"></script>
     <script>
            
        </script> 
        
    </head>
   
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                     <h1><strong>FORM</strong></h1>
                     <hr id="hr2" style="border: 6px solid palevioletred" >
                <div id="black">
                     <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/users">
                        <fieldset>


                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name : </label>  
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                          <input id="textinput" name="name" placeholder="Enter Username" class="form-control input-md" type="text" value="Name" onfocus="if (this.value=='Name') this.value='';">

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Age : </label>  
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                          <input id="textinput" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age" class="form-control input-md" type="number">

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Button -->
                        <!-- Button (Double) -->
                        <div class="form-group">

                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button id="singlebutton" name="button1id" class="btn btn-success">Add User</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>

            <body>

                 <h1><strong>USERS</strong></h1>
                 <hr id="hr1" style="border: 6px solid #7ec4ec;" >
                 <ul id="list" class="triangle">
                    <% for(var i=0; i<userlist.length; i++) {%>
                       <li><%= userlist[i].name %> : <%= userlist[i].age %> <a href="#" onclick="delete_element('<%= userlist[i]._id %>')" id="delete">Delete</a> ||  <a href="#" onclick="update_element()">Update</a></li>
                    <% } %>
                 </ul>
            </body>


                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

**EDIT**:

This is my **frontend.js**

```js
var $ = require('jquery');
function delete_element (userId) { 
     $.post('delete/user/',userId,function(){
         
         alert('Deleting....'); //For now i have just added an alert.
     }); 
}
```

This is my new **users.js**

```js
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User=require('../models/usermodel.js');
var $= require('jquery');
    
/* GET users listing. */


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({},function(err,userModel){
      res.render('userview',{userlist:userModel});
  });
});


router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    
    var newUser = new User({
          name:req.body.name,
          age: req.body.age         
    });
    
    console.log(newUser);
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('User created!');
    });

});


router.post("delete/user/:id", deleteUser); 

function deleteUser(req,res){
    
    User.findById(req.params.id).remove().exec(function(err){
         if (!err) {
                console.log('Removed Successfully');
        }
        else {
                console.log('Error in removing the entry');
        }
    });
}


  /*
function delete_element(id){
    
        $('#delete').on("click",function(){
           $(this).parent().remove(); 
        });
      User.remove({_id: req.body.id }, function(err) {
        if (!err) {
                console.log('Removed Successfully');
        }
        else {
                console.log('Error in removing the entry');
        }
      
          }); 
} 
     */               



/*router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    userModel.update( {name: req.params.name}, { $pullAll: {uid: [req.params.deleteUid] } } )
   
});*/







module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the user's _id in your delete link :

```
onclick="delete_element('<%= userlist[i]._id %>')"
```

This will produce :

```
onclick="delete_element('55510c6cf0e19f6414b30f97')"
```

and pass the user's _id to your delete function.

**Edit**

Okay so, apparently, you're trying to call a function defined on the server (Node), directly from your view (HTML).
That's absolutely not how it works :)

`onclick="delete_element()"` is calling a function locally, in your browser. The console (F12) must yell `error : delete_element is undefined`.

So the way to go is the following :

1) Create a javascript function (not in Node, in your front-end application) that will call the server.

```
function delete_element (userId) { // This will be called on click and passed the user's _id
     $.post('delete/user/'+userId) // This calls the server. Todo : add a callback, etc.
}
```

2) Your Node server must have a corresponding route that will receive the call :

```
router.post("delete/user/:id", deleteUser); // This is reached when the client calls post('delete/user/1a2b3c4d'). The id is read with req.params.id

deleteUser = (req,res) => {
     User.findById(req.params.id)
         .remove()
         .exec( error => { // Reply to the client, otherwise the request will hang and timeout.
             if(error) return res.status(500).send(error);
             res.status(200).end()
         })
}
```

That's for the first question, please create a new question for the second one.

Comment: still doesn't work. Is the delete_element () function correct?

Comment: Yean, the Mongoose call seems correct. What does your `delete_element` function look like (the front-side one, not the one in Node) ?

Comment: There is none like that.

Comment: or....... are you trying to call a function defined on the server (Node), directly from your view (HTML), without any other operation in-between?? O_o

Comment: i would say yes. Please guide me if that is absurd. Im relatively new to the field.

Comment: Okay... So I have updated my answer with a super quick tutorial :)

Comment: Thank you. So i need to link the front end file in my .ejs file.?

Comment: Well, the front-end part typically consists in some HTML (which is generated by EJS in your case), some javascript and CSS. So yeah, the HTML page calls a JS file... My guess is that you should take a few beginner courses before messing up with Mongoose, Node, EJS and stuff :)

Comment: Hi. I have edited my ejs and users.js accordingly. Have added a frontend.js file in my public/javascripts folder. However its till notifies, delete_element() not defined. Could you take a look into it please? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well it's almost impossible to know without the files. Did you include the JS file in your HTML page? Like, `<script src="frontend.js"></script>` ?